# How can I refactor my code having multiple if conditions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, if-statement, ecmascript-6

How can I simplify my code having multiple if conditions.

```
    var displayOption;
    if (category === "new" && URIParams.displayOptions) {
        if (URIParams.displayOptions === "showStartingPrice") {
            displayOption = "showStartingPrice";
        } else {
            displayOption = URIParams.displayOptions.split(",")[1];
        }
    }
    if (displayOption && Static.displayOptions[displayOption] === "displayStartingPrice" && model.minPrice && model.minPrice[0]) {
        model.minimumPrice = `Starting at $${model.minPrice[0].value}`;
        model.price = true;
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want to achieve and what have you tried?

Comment: I wrote the above code now I want to get rid of multiple if conditions.

Comment: Why would you want to get rid of them, perhaps they re okay to be there? Just for the sake of having shorter code, doesn't mean it 'better' :)

Comment: The only(?) generic way to get rid of multple checks is to store/convert the data to byte codes, and do some bit logic with the data. That way you'll need only a single check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```js
NavigationInventory.handleStartingPrice = function (URIParams, model, category) {
    var displayOption;

    if (category === "new" && URIParams.displayOptions) {
        displayOption = (URIParams.displayOptions === "showStartingPrice" ? "showStartingPrice" : URIParams.displayOptions.split(",")[1]);

        if (displayOption && Static.displayOptions[displayOption] === "displayStartingPrice" && model.minPrice && model.minPrice[0]) {
             model.minimumPrice = `Starting at $${model.minPrice[0].value}`;
             model.price = true;
        }
    }
}
```

1. By using a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), the nested `if` statement for setting `displayOption` can be removed
2. The last `if` statement can be nested inside the first because if the first condition is not met, then `displayOption` evaluates to `false` in any case.